# How to add an internal signal to the waveform viewer in Aldec HDL for a Lattice Machxo3

Tags: lattice, activehdl

I'm absolutelty no FPGA expert, but designed a device with Quartus and used Modelsim to simulate it. I was then told to modify the design and make it work with a Lattice device as they changed their mind about Altera (mainly down to Lattice devices being a bucket load cheaper I think).

Unfortunatelty (for me) Lattice Diamond comes with this Aldec-HDL program instead of Modelsim. After stuggling for a couple of days I have managed to finally work out how to be able to tweak my workbench and re-run the simulation without having to relaunch [Active HDL] from Diamond. However, after a further couple of days of trying, I just cannot work out how to add internal signals to the waveform viewer.

On Modelsim one of the few intuitive features is that you can select an instantiation of a particular component, pick one or more of its signals and just add it to the waveform viewer. On Active-HDL I can't even find a way of picking a particular instantiation of a module. I can find a way of picking a module, but its signals just say "Unavailable". That doesn't seem particularly helpful anyway as you need to be able to select an instantiation of a component, not just the component definition.

I assume this must be possible, otherwise it's a pretty useless simulator. Can anyone enlighten me on how to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

OK, always seems weird answering your own question, but this might save people a lot of time in the future.

The big important thing here is that in Design | Settings | Access to Design Objects, you must **UNTICK** "Limit Read Access to design top level signal only".

Then, once you have compiled the the testbench you can add all/any signals from the instantiated units that appear in the Structure Tab when simulation is initialised.

Obv, really.

Hope this stops other people going insane.